# How do I take screenshots in Windows Virtual PC

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, microsoft-virtual-pc, screenshot

When I press Alt-Print Screen I get a screenshot of the entire VM+window frame taken in my host-OS.  What I want is a screenshot of the selected application running in the VM.

My host OS is win7-64 enterprise.  The VM is running XP Pro.

Comment: If you run Virtual PC in full screen and do Alt-PrtSc, does it still capture the windows frame?

Comment: Thank you.  Running the VM full screen instead of windowed resulted in the behavior I expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the keyboard is captured by guest, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> should capture the guest's screen contents, not the host's. If you have VM Additions installed to the guest, you may need to move the mouse cursor inside guest's screen.

Also make sure you're pressing the **left** <kbd>Alt</kbd>, because <kbd>AltGr</kbd> (RightAlt) is usually reserved by VirtualPC as the "escape to host" key.

If all else fails, cutting off the unneeded part in Paint or Photoshop is not *that* hard anyway.

Comment: Good old Paint. :D

Comment: Left vs Right alt didn't matter.  It was running the VM fullscreened that did the trick.

Manually cropping one image in paint isn't that bad.  Doing several dozen when you need to get the borders correct to the pixel instead of just being close is annoyingly time consuming since it ends up taking roughly a minute per image.

Answer (score 2):

just goto edit menu and select all, at same menu click on copy and past in paint. that's it.